# How to post multiple values at same key using Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit, retrofit2

I am stuck on this part which requires me to post multiple values to the server. I am using Retrofit.

The whole scenario is like this: there is a form where user can fill in the details like his name, age, address and can even select multiple values from certain questions. Particularly, there are 5 types of questions: Int, String, Single Choice, Boolean and Multiple Choice. As you can see I can have Int, String, Boolean and Array types.

So I created FieldMap as > to save all values in it and then posting it. I am able to post all values except Array which my server is expecting as query dict i.e. if I have FieldMap as "143": ["hello", "hey", "hi"]; server is expecting me to send it as 143=hello&143=hey&143=hi.

It is expecting me to send all array values to same key as shown above.

Can somebody help me with this? How can I achieve this using Retrofit 2?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sth like following?

```
@GET("endpoint")
fun getSomething(@Query("143") items: List<String>): Call<Response>
```